How manage Location Permissions with car app
i need fire a request and start a service that send the same request periodically to do a kind of tracking of my current position. All this logic is implemented in my mobile app.
but now I need start the tacking from one action in my car app, so I have to manage location permission in my car app before send the request.
Could you guide me in the correct way to do that?
